# Associative Array Count Php

Tags: php, arrays

I got Array

```
   array(
    0 => array(
        "element1" => "A",
        "place" => "B"
    ),
    1 => array(
        "element1" => "A",
        "place" => Y
    ),
2=> array(
        "element1" => "B",
        "place" => Y
    )
    )
```

I want to get unique `element1`s  value  count. Is there any short way ? For example there one "A" in "element1" and one "B" in "element1". **Result is 2**, something like group by in MySQL.

Comment: what do you mean by  "element1" ' s count ?

Comment: I want to get unique "element1"'s count. There is 1  "A".

Comment: Have you tried these functions http://in3.php.net/array_key_exists and  http://in2.php.net/array_keys these may help

Comment: @user3222643 What is then with `$array[1]['element1']`? Maybe you should provide a better example array, as it is not completely clear what exactly you're aiming to achieve.

Comment: I edited again question.

Comment: I edited my answer, look at it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 5.5 , you could do like this..

Since you needed `unique` as per your comment.

```
echo count(array_unique(array_column($arr,'element1')));
```

### The code

```
<?php
$arr=array(0=>array("element1"=>"A","place"=>"B"),1=>array("element1"=>A,"place"=>Y));
echo count(array_unique(array_column($arr,'element1'))); //"prints" 1
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/98130)

Answer (score 0):

### <kbd>[**working demo**](http://codepad.org/SRxkgBJ6)</kbd>

This is exactly what you want :

```
$arr = array(
    0=>array("element1"=>"A","place"=>"B"),
    1=>array("element1"=>"B","place"=>"Y")
    );
foreach($arr as $val){
    $res[$val['element1']][] = 1;
}
echo count($res);
```

### Result

`2`

Comment: It s not what ı am asking